# Kitchen sink is leaking after running for a few seconds

Tags: kitchen-sink

https://imgur.com/WBEolnV
The kitchen sink drips where the black cylinder is after a few seconds of the water being on. I dont know if it is a tightning issue as it is hard to turn or the faucet. The Brand is Elkay.

Comment: It sounds as if you need a new faucet.  These are rarely reparable.

Comment: I don't see a black cylinder in the picture?